# I am not getting any error , exception and also not getting any output on browser

Tags: spring, jsp

Online shopping project in spring mvc.

[image: This is output]

This is my Controller class the where i am fetching url but not getting any output.
I am using session for storing cart values.

check my code it is correct for store customer order in a database.

**OrderController.java**

```
  @Controller
  public class orderController 
   {

@Autowired
private orderDaoInterface orderDao;

@Autowired
private cartDaoInterface cartdao;

@RequestMapping("/order/${id}")
public String createOrder(@PathVariable(value = "id") int id) {
    customerOrderModel customerOrder = new customerOrderModel();
    Cart cart = cartdao.getCartByID(id);
    customerOrder.setCart(cart);

    CustomerModel customer = cart.getCustomer();
    customerOrder.setCustomerID(customer);
    customerOrder.setBillingAddress(customer.getBillingAddress());
    customerOrder.setShippingAddress(customer.getShippingAddress());

    orderDao.addCustomerOrder(customerOrder);

    return "redirect:/view/cart/addItem";
   }
```

**CartDao.java**

```
     @Repository
     @Transactional
     public class cartDao implements cartDaoInterface {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

 public Cart getCartByID(int CartID) 
 {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();           
    return (Cart) session.get(Cart.class, CartID);
}
```

}

**CartModel.java**

```
  @Entity
   public class Cart {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;
private String name;
private BigDecimal price;
private int quantity;

private CustomerModel customer;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public CustomerModel getCustomer() {
    return customer;
}
```

**CustomerOrder_Model.java**

```
 @Entity
  public class customerOrderModel {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
   private String  OrderID;

   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="ID")
   private CustomerModel customerID;

   @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name = "Cartid")
   private Cart cart;
```

Comment: Start with a minimal example. Like a GetMapping for hello world and work up from there. You're RequestMapping refers to "/order/${id}". You're calling /Product/order?id. Is your app deployed as Product? Also your mapping says /order/id, so you would need /Product/order/123 instead of /Product/order?id=123

Comment: i change it as you says still no output showing.

Answer (score 0):

modify the `createOrder` method is as follows,

```
@RequestMapping("/order/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String createOrder(@PathVariable int id) {
    --------
}
```

if order id is 001, then ulr should be,

```
http://localhost:8007/Product/order/001
```

jsp,

```
<a class="btn btn-light btn-xl" href="<c:url value="/order/${items.id}">Order Now!</a>
```

Comment: I want your opinion.  how can i order list of items present in card at once on click on order now .

Comment: No plz check my url.                                                                  <a class="btn btn-light btn-xl" href="<c:url value="/order"/>/${items.id}">Order Now!</a>

Comment: refer the modified answer. what is your browser output?